# dompdf , I have the calculations I have to put in my pdf, what should I?

Tags: javascript, php, dompdf

I have the calculations in my javascript and I have to put in my pdf, what should I do?

here is my javascript

```js
 <script>
function hitung(){ 

var e = (document.getElementById("ifin").value);
var a = (document.getElementById("Furniture").value);
var panjang =(document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
var ht = 0.0;
var hf = 0.0;
var total = 0.0;

if (e == "hpl") {

    hf = 0.0;
   }
else if(e == "cat")
   {
    hf = 0.5;
}
else {
    hf = 0.0;
}
if (a == "kitchen"){
    ht = 1.7; 
}
else if (a == "meja"){
    ht = 2.3; 
}
else {
    ht = 0.0;
}
total = panjang*ht+hf;
document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML ="Harga Total : Rp."+total.toFixed(2)+"0.000,00"+"<br>Sudah termasuk ongkir";
}



</script>
```

i want to input my total to dompdf, here is my dompdf script

```
<?php

$nama = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($_POST['nama']));
$alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$total = $_POST['<script>var = total</script>']
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

?>
```

i try to insert total like this `$total = $_POST['<script>var = total</script>']` but it doesnt work

what i supposed to do??

Comment: Syntax Errors, that's what I see. Did you read the [Quick Start](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)?

Comment: what do u mean??

Comment: `$_POST['<script>var = total</script>']` would mean you have an HTML input name, or AJAX post property `'<script>var = total</script>'`, which makes no sense. I would like to make a long distance molecular transfer device, but have no understanding of molecular physics, so I can't. You will have to understand PHP basics, first, before using any libraries.